# WebView onpagefinished not called for second time

Tags: android, webview

I am using Webview to load url, for the first time everything works properly. If I load the url second time (for refreshing the page and also for loading a different url), onPageFinished is not fired.

```
mWvClient = new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "page has finished loading");      
    }
};   

mWebView.loadUrl(mAirLinesData.getUrl());
mWebView.setWebViewClient(mWvClient);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to first set the Client, and then Load your URLs

```
mWvClient = new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "page has finished loading");
    }
};   

mWebView.setWebViewClient(mWvClient);
mWebView.loadUrl(mAirLinesData.getUrl());
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the webView first and then load the URL. Also, try to overload all other methods of WebViewClient (with only one instance of web view) and see if that helps.